# Linux script with netcat

Tags: linux, bash

**Solution**

```
while read -r line
do
        echo $line
done < <(nc -l -p 4001)
```

With the command

```
nc -l -p 4001 -v
```

I can listen to port 4001 to my barcode scanner (working without script).

I've tried to write a bash script like this

```
while true do

  if [ nc -l -p 4001 -v ] then
    echo "barcode incoming"
  fi

done
```

How can i check if `nc -l -p 4001 -v` is not empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this by checking return status of `nc` command:

```
while true; do

  if nc -l 4001; then
     echo "barcode incoming"
  else
     sleep 1
  fi

done
```

Comment: Your code can be made simpler: `if nc -l -w 3 -p 4001 -v; then`.

Comment: @anubhava It's not working for me. When I'm run this script i get `Connection from 192.168.100.111:5011`. Now i can scan my barcode but the echo **barcode incoming** does not appear.

Comment: You will see `"barcode incoming"` only after client closes connection as `nc` command just listens on given port.

Answer (score 0):

What's the complete output you are seeing?

I tried the same, i see the below prints:

```
listening on [any] 7000 ...
10.62.73.59: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host
connect to [10.63.61.231] from (UNKNOWN) [10.62.73.59] 48138
./tt_DIR/0000755000175000017500000000000012407172607011306 5ustar  sdlcbsdlcbbarcode incoming
listening on [any] 7000 ...
```

"barcode incoming" is getting printed in my case.